# Odoo get another model fields used in specific view

Tags: inheritance, view, module, model, odoo

I'm working on Odoo 10 and developing a module to add new functionalities to the stock module, but I'm facing two problems when I'm on a good merchandise entry (with the list of products to transfert into wharehouse):

**- First, I would like to extend the View0 (stock_picking_views.xml, record: view_picking_form) by adding a new computed field in the "Operations" tree view. But when I try to add this field Odoo tells me it doesn't exist:**

> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/odoo-10.0.post20170508-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 1083, in _validate_fields
>       raise ValidationError("%s\n\n%s" % (_("Error while validating constraint"), tools.ustr(e)))
>   ParseError: "Error while validating constraint
>
> Field `computed_field` does not exist

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    _inherit = ['stock.picking']

    computed_field = fields.Float(string='my field', default=0.0, compute='_computefield')

    @api.depends('pack_operation_ids.fieldA', 'pack_operation_ids.fieldB')
    def _computefield(self):
        self.computed_field = self.pack_operation_ids.fieldA - self.pack_operation_ids.fieldB
```

I don't understand because I'm able to add the computed_field in another page of the View0, where it appears well and is computed each time other values changes. So any idea on what I'm doing wrong ? I'm new to Odoo and there is probably a lot of things I'm missing for now.

**- Second issue, I've created a button which open a new window above this View0. And I would like to get some fields shown on the View0.** But I don't know how to do it because these View0 fields are not clearly defined in View0 model (stock.picking). They are all put into a Many2one field from stock.pack.operation and accessed with functions in the stock.picking model.

My second model also inherit from stock.picking:

```
class MyModel2(models.Model):
    _name = 'stock.picking.model2'
    _inherit = ['stock.picking']
```

A help on these to issues would be really helpful, and if I need to precise something don't hesitates to tell me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

### Part 1 of your question:

It sounds like you are trying to add a new field into the Operations tree view.

The problem with your attempt is that you added your `computed_field` onto the `stock.picking` module. Once you are adding fields within the `pack_operation_product_ids` (Operations tree view), the model is `stock.pack.operation`. If the `computed_field` is not also available to that model, then Odoo will give the error you have received.

---

### Part 2 of your question:

I would need to see more details about what exactly you are trying to do.

- Why are you creating an entirely new model, `stock.picking.model2`?
- What fields are you trying to display on the wizard (popup form view)?

Comment: Thanks travisw, I add some details to the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your answer travisw,

**For part 1,**
I understand know, it was logical but I didn't see it. I suppose I just have to add the field into the stock.pack.operation table so, thanks :)

**For part 2,** 
I want a wizard with a new design. And if I'm not wrong (tell me if so), if I don't create a new model I have to inherit from the active view and modify from that, and it's not what I want.

The only thing I need from the active view to create the wizard, is the products related to the goods entry (product_id, qty_done, product_qty).

I made some additional researches, and found that it could be done by retrieving the active view id with the context and then find a way to retrieve good fields thanks to that ? Is it possible in this case and do you know how ?

Comment: I suggest at this point you make a second question with all the details about creating your wizard. I will say that, typically, when you're creating a wizard, you would use `models.TransientModel` and only define the fields you need (rather than inheriting the entire model, as you've done). Finally, you would get the `active_id` into the wizard by defining a `context` variable on the action that opens the wizard. Based on that, you should be able to get the other data via an `onchange` method (recommended) or using `default_field_name` as a part of the context for each field.